# How to get a custom error message from API, using the Redux toolkit in React Js

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

In my backend application, I am sending an error of status code 404 with the message:

```
 return res
        .status(404)
        .send({ message: "You need to complete the previous step" });
```

And in the front end, I am Using the Redux toolkit for handling the API Request with Axios.
My main goal is, every time if I get an error, I will set the error message as the message I sent from the backend.

```
export const createCourse = createAsyncThunk(
  "test",
  async (id) => {
    return axios.post(`backendurl`,{});
     }
);
```

But the problem I faced was that when the reducer gets rejected, it doesn't give me the message that I was sent from the backend.

```
.addCase(createCourse.rejected, (state, action) => {
      console.log(action);  
      state.isLoading = false;
      })
```

Here is the console of this problem:

```
{
    "type": "/assignedjobs/create/:id/rejected",
    "meta": {
        "arg": "63bbd17d322112937f248099",
        "requestId": "-6wZtw96-43ykgyeRRh7I",
        "rejectedWithValue": false,
        "requestStatus": "rejected",
        "aborted": false,
        "condition": false
    },
    "error": {
        "name": "AxiosError",
        "message": "Request failed with status code 404",
        "stack": "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404\n    at settle (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:201425:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:200133:66)",
        "code": "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"
    }
}
```

How can I get the error message in my action payload if it gets rejected?

I am trying to achieve this by trycatch block in Axios but it doesnt make any change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you need to do like that.

```
export const createCourse = createAsyncThunk(
  'create-course', async (data, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const result = await axios.post(`backendurl`, data)
      return result.data
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response.status === 404) {
        return rejectWithValue({ message: error.response.data.message })
      }
      return rejectWithValue({message: 'Some Other message'})
    }
  }
)
```

inside reducer

```
.addCase(createCourse.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.error = action.payload.message
      state.isLoading = false;
      })
```

Result of *error.response*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can access the error message in the error object :

```
.addCase(createCourse.rejected, (state, action) => {
    console.log(action.error.message);
    state.isLoading = false;
    state.error = action.error.message;
})
```